# How to mimic execl() in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, process, exec, file-descriptor

I have an old application written in C++ which I am porting to Ruby.

One section of the code uses `execl()`, in order to replace the process with a[n updated] copy of itself while maintaining open file descriptors (this application is a network service).

```c
  if ( execl( "./my-app", "-restart", fd.c_str(), NULL ) < 0 ) {
```

Didn't take long to figure out that Ruby has no `execl()` equivalent, but that you can fake it in part using `Process::spawn` and the `:close_others` option. Or, at least I should be able to according to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Process.html#method-c-spawn):

> file descriptor inheritance: close non-redirected non-standard fds (3, 4, 5, ...) or not
>   :close_others => true  : don't inherit

So, it seems to me that the following should spawn a new process which has access to all open file descriptors of the parent:

```rb
server_fd = @server.to_i
env = {
  "APP_REBOOT"    => "true",
  "APP_SERVER_FD" => server_fd.to_s,
}
command = "ruby my-app.rb"
options = {
  :in           => :in,
  :out          => :out,
  :err          => :err,
  :close_others => false,
}
pid = Process.spawn env, command, options
Process.detach pid
```

Which will allow the child access to the descriptors... however I cannot figure out how to `exit` the parent process without closing all the descriptors. In other words, if I cause the parent to `exit` at the end of the code:

```rb
server_fd = @server.to_i
env = {
  "APP_REBOOT"    => "true",
  "APP_SERVER_FD" => server_fd.to_s,
}
command = "ruby my-app.rb"
options = {
  :in           => :in,
  :out          => :out,
  :err          => :err,
  :close_others => false,
}
pid = Process.spawn env, command, options
Process.detach pid
exit # ADDED THIS LINE
```

Then the descriptors are also closed for the child.

I have a feeling this is more a problem with my approach to process management than something specific to Ruby but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

---

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

**EDIT1**
Just before my call to `Process.spawn` (or `Process.exec` as @mata points out) I have a diagnostic output:

```rb
system 'lsof -c ruby'
```

And another call to that just inside my `recover_from_reboot` method. This is the tail of output pre-reboot, you can see the listening server port and a connected client on the last two lines:

```
ruby    8957 chris    0u   CHR    136,1      0t0        4 /dev/pts/1
ruby    8957 chris    1u   CHR    136,1      0t0        4 /dev/pts/1
ruby    8957 chris    2u   CHR    136,1      0t0        4 /dev/pts/1
ruby    8957 chris    3r  FIFO      0,8      0t0 12213372 pipe
ruby    8957 chris    4w  FIFO      0,8      0t0 12213372 pipe
ruby    8957 chris    5r  FIFO      0,8      0t0 12213373 pipe
ruby    8957 chris    6w  FIFO      0,8      0t0 12213373 pipe
ruby    8957 chris    7u  IPv4 12213374      0t0      TCP localhost.localdomain:boks-servc (LISTEN)
ruby    8957 chris    8u  IPv4 12213423      0t0      TCP localhost.localdomain:boks-servc->localhost.localdomain:45249 (ESTABLISHED)
```

And this is what I see post-reboot:

```
ruby    8957 chris    3r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 12203947 pipe
ruby    8957 chris    4w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 12203947 pipe
ruby    8957 chris    5r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 12203948 pipe
ruby    8957 chris    6w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 12203948 pipe
```

Again this is whether I try `spawn` or `exec`.

---

**EDIT2**
Given my diagnostic output, I see that the server keeps binding to fd 7, and the client to 8. By adding

```rb
7 => 7,
8 => 8,
```

to my `options` array, I am able to successfully persist these sockets across reboot using `exec`. It is feasible for me to manually add the server and `[client1, client2,...]` `fd`s to the options hash, but this seems very dirty when `:close_others` is supposed to do the heavy lifting for me.

Comment: why not just use [`exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Process.html#method-c-exec)? It does everything that `execl` does in C...

Comment: Good call @mata, unfortunately I still see the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly isn't the solution I was looking for, but in the absence of any revelations about the `:close_options` Hash and `Process.spawn` or `Process.exec`, I wound up manually adding all the file descriptors I cared about to the `option`s array, which did the trick:

```rb
server_fd  = self.server.to_i
client_fds = self.clients.map { |c| c.get_fd }
env = {
  "APP_REBOOT"     => "true",
  "APP_SERVER_FD"  => server_fd.to_s,
  "APP_CLIENT_FDS" => Marshal.dump(client_fds),
}
options = {
  :in           => :in,
  :out          => :out,
  :err          => :err,
  :close_others => false,
}
# Add the server socket to the options Hash.
options[server_fd] = server_fd
# Add all the client sockets to the options Hash.
@clients.each { |c| options[c.get_fd] = c.get_fd }
# Begin anew.
Process.exec env, App.binary.to_s, options
```

*I'll leave this answer unaccepted for a while, in case anyone comes along to set the record straight.*